# convert SQL statement of same table join to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a working Postgres SQL statement that performs a table -- `question` -- joining on itself to only extract rows with matching `foo` column that have the most recent `created_data`:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM question q
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT foo, MAX(created_date) AS most_current
    FROM question
    GROUP BY foo) grouped_q 
ON q.foo = grouped_q.foo 
AND q.created_date = grouped_q.most_current
```

I'm interested if and how this could be converted to SQLAlchemy, such that I could take advantage of the resulting rows as ORM objects?

And, if known, what kind of performance differences there might be?

FWIW, I'm able to hydrate a SQLAlchemy ORM object by looping through rows and doing the following...

```
for row in res.fetchall():
    question = Question(**dict(zip(res.keys(), row)))
```

but this feels kludgy, and I'd like to keep the query in SQLAlchemy syntax if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty close to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920397/use-raw-sql-in-an-orm-query, though the way to perform [tag:greatest-n-per-group] is slightly different.

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä, reckon you're right, and I'm betting I can derive a working answer from that.  Will post an answer if so.

Comment: Here's another post you might find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311354/sqlalchemy-joining-with-subquery-issue. Namely it shows the syntax for a join with a subquery.